# HTML default namespace vs. explicit namespace

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xml-namespaces

Why is this not rendering correctly on Chrome:

```xml
<h:html xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <h:head/>
  <h:body>
    <h:ul>
      <h:li>
        A
      </h:li>
      <h:li>
        B
      </h:li> 
    </h:ul>
  </h:body>
</h:html>
```

While this does render correctly? :

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head/>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        A
      </li>
      <li>
        B
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here? Doens't default namespace supposed to behave the same as specifying namespace explicitly?

Comment: HTML is not XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not XML.

Your code works fine, when I test it in Chrome, with an `application/xml` Content-Type.

It doesn't work as `text/html`.

HTML allows an `xmlns` attribute for compatibility with XML, and it allows some XML (such as SVG) to be embedded in it, but an HTML parser won't support namespace aliases for HTML elements.